# How can I make a jQuery "ready" event handler fire after all the other ones?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I am working on a Greasemonkey script that will actually upgrade the version of jQuery used on the page. To do this, I need to add a "ready" event handler that will fire after all the other ones that might be on the page.

I know that jQuery waits for the DOM to be manipulable before invoking the ready event handlers, so is there a way to influence the order in which it executes them? Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are called in the order they are registered. So from the top of the page to the bottom. If you need this to be the last registered ready callback register it at the very end of the body tag. Also use the `$(window).load` as opposed to `$(document).ready`.

Comment: Thanks! Most jQuery scripts use `ready`, and since `load` usually first after `ready`, this was just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The ready handlers are added to a `readyList` Array, which I'm pretty sure is private, so I don't think you'll be able to influence it directly.

One thing you could perhaps do is add your code to the `readyList`, but place it in a `setTimeout()` so it waits a bit to execute. Hopefully all the others will be done first.

Still, you may have troubles when upgrading jQuery like this. For example, there may be differences in the implementation of `jQuery.cache` which stores event handlers, and other data.

So if `jQuery.cache` was populated with one version, it may not be compatible with another.

Answer (score 1):

[How to control the order of functions being called in jQuery $(document).ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320326/how-to-control-the-order-of-functions-being-called-in-jquery-document-ready)

According to answers given to the question above, they should fire in the order they are added (the ajax-calls in that specific question add more mud to the water than in your question).

Comment: You're welcome! Sounds like an interesting plugin, upgrading jQuery on the fly... will it be on Userscripts sometime soon?

Comment: Sure will ;). It will be part of the next rewrite of my Gametrailers Spam Killer script (http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/88577). Gametrailers uses jQuery version 1.3.1. I wanted to add jQuery UI Dialogs and other controls, and I didn't want to mess with legacy editions of UI. I'll probably also make a post about upgrading jQuery on my blog (see bio).