# Adding attributes to an anchor in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-mobile, attributes, anchor

I want to add custom attribute settings to a generated anchor link of Wordpress.
This is to let Jquery Mobile find the attributes and makes a button out of it.

Every anchor link, which is generated in Wordpress via PHP, contains the page_item class. So my guess is to search for the needed 'page_item' class and just add the needed attribute information to generate the needed button.

My header.php file contains the following links to the needed Jquery libraries:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
```

I wanted to use the following code to add attributes to my anchor links but I just can't seem to let it work. (This code is placed in the header of the header.php file)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
                    $('.page_item').ready(function(){
                     $(this).attr('data-transition', 'pop');
                     $(this).attr('data-icon', 'arrow-r');
                     $(this).attr('data-iconpos', 'left');
                     $(this).attr('data-role', 'button');
                    });

        </script>
```

When checking the code via firebug Wordpress generates the following code:

```
<ul>

                    <li class="page_item page-item-5"><a href="http://localhost/ddwp/?page_id=5">Home</a>
<ul class='children'>
<li class="page_item page-item-11"><a href="http://localhost/ddwp/?page_id=11">Link1</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-17"><a href="http://localhost/ddwp/?page_id=17">Link2</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-21"><a href="http://localhost/ddwp/?page_id=21">Link3</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-23"><a href="http://localhost/ddwp/?page_id=23">Link4</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-62 current_page_item"><a href="http://localhost/ddwp/?page_id=62">Link5</a></li>
                </ul>
```

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards
Dragon54

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few reasons your script isn't working.  Here's some suggestions, and some code that is tested to apply the attributes you are after to the links in the navigation:

1. You might consider moving the `ready` away from each separate call to a function that  contains all of the calls rather than for each call separately. (I have done that below for you).
2. `.page_item` is not a link, it is an li element.  Also note that this is ONLY the navigation links - it will not apply to any links in the content of the pages/posts.
3. Jquery in WordPress is not always safe to run using `$`.  By wrapping the calls in a document ready called with `jQuery`, you can still use `$` within the function to call the jQuery functions.

   ```
   jQuery(function($) {
       $('.page_item a').each(function(){
           $(this).attr('data-transition', 'pop');
           $(this).attr('data-icon', 'arrow-r');
           $(this).attr('data-iconpos', 'left');
           $(this).attr('data-role', 'button');
       });
   });
   ```

**EDIT :**
Per the excellent comments by @Jasper the **much better** way to do this would be:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.page_item a').attr({ 'data-transition' : 'pop', 
            'data-icon' : 'arrow-r', 
            'data-iconpos' : 'left', 
            'data-role' : 'button' });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks cale_b this code did add the needed attributes but my page still did not changed those links into buttons. Any suggestions? This is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CfvLZ/) to make thing more clear. Maybe it's better for me to ask this 'button problem' in a new question on the website?

Comment: It has to do with the order of the jQuery running.  If jQuery mobile is running BEFORE you are changing the attributes, then it would not pick up the additional attributes.  Your script, I assume is AFTER the load of the jQuery mobile code, which means it's running AFTER the jQuery mobile code has already run.  According to [This stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320326/how-to-control-the-order-of-functions-being-called-in-jquery-document-ready), you have limited control.  You could TRY moving your script after the jQuery script, and BEFORE the jQuery Mobile script.

Comment: Ofcourse! Thank you very much! That solved my 'button problem'. Hope you have a nice day! ;)

Comment: This code should be at least chained (no reason to make the `$(this)` selection four times), but more than that you can optimize the use of the `.attr()` function quite a bit here by passing it an object map of the desired attribute changes: `$(this).attr({ 'data-transition' : 'pop', 'data-icon' : 'arrow-r', 'data-iconpos' : 'left', 'data-role' : 'button' });`: http://api.jquery.com/attr

Comment: @Jasper - thank you.  This is why I love stackoverflow - I'm always learning new things.  You are right about chaining. Sometimes I don't go into those bits when working within the question's original structure.  I should have proposed it as an option.  I did not, however, know about the ability to add multiple attributes through the `.attr()` function, so thank you!

Comment: Now that I look at this again, the loop isn't necessary: `$('.page_item a').attr({ 'data-transition' : 'pop', 'data-icon' : 'arrow-r', 'data-iconpos' : 'left', 'data-role' : 'button' });`. The loop is only necessary if you want to do something different to each of the elements (like change the transition type based on a class on the element). And it really isn't necessary for that anyway because you can pass `.attr()` a function in which you can do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

`$.ready()` is a special event for document loading, and only works on the document. You need to iterate through the items using `$.each()` instead.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.page_item').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-transition', 'pop');
    $(this).attr('data-icon', 'arrow-r');
    $(this).attr('data-iconpos', 'left');
    $(this).attr('data-role', 'button');
  });
});
```

Comment: Not being pedantic but the code should be $(this).data('transition', 'pop'); - no need for .attr()

Comment: I just kept his code as is. As for me, I wouldn't duplicate `$(this)` either.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('li.page_item a').each(function () {
        jQuery(this).attr({
            'data-transition': 'pop',
            'data-icon': 'arrow-r',
            'data-iconpos': 'left',
            'data-role': 'button'
        });
    });
});
```

or just

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('li.page_item a').attr({
        'data-transition': 'pop',
        'data-icon': 'arrow-r',
        'data-iconpos': 'left',
        'data-role': 'button'
    });
});
```