# Custom data attributes in WordPress widget links

Tags: wordpress, jquery-mobile

I'm building a mobile website with WordPress and jQuery Mobile.

I would like to create a custom widget area appearing when the user taps on a button.

I would like the links contained in the widget area look like JQM buttons. To do that I should add the attribute data-role="button" to the 'a' elements in the widget.

Is there a way to add a custom attribute to these 'a' elements from functions.php?

By default, this is the code of a link in a widget:

```
<h3 class="widget-title">Categories</h3>
  <ul>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-646">
      <a title="Some title" href="http://example.com/category/">Category</a>
    </li>
    ...
```

I need to add a data-role attribute inside 'a' element:

```
<a title="Some title" href="http://example.com/category/" data-role="button">Category</a>
```

I would like to know if WP API provides a filter to do that from functions.php, or if it is possible in some way with PHP

Comment: Yes it's possible to add custom attribute and call it.

Comment: It's easy to do with a little js, as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030953/adding-attributes-to-an-anchor-in-wordpress 
But I would like to filter link data from within my theme functions.php

Comment: Can you post code of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Just edited my original question adding code

Comment: You can filter links this way. `$('li.cat-item').find('a').each(function () { $(this).attr('data-role', 'button') });`

Comment: Thank you, Omar. Actually, this is the solution I've just adopted.

Comment: Great ill add an answer with more info.

Answer (score 1):

To filter links and add `data-role=button` to them, use the below code.

```
$('li.cat-item').find('a').each(function () {
 $(this).attr('data-role', 'button');
});
```

Where `.cat-item` is a class of list items.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the answer to my question: how to add custom data attributes to WP menu items from functions.php.

It is possibile to manipulate the markup of WordPress menus (and not only menus).
WP provides the Walker class, which can be extended in functions.php.

I don't reproduce the code here, but who's interested in WP menu building, can grab it from here:

http://www.kriesi.at/archives/improve-your-wordpress-navigation-menu-output

Other useful resourcer from WP stackexchange are the following:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14037/menu-items-description-custom-walker-for-wp-nav-menu/

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19245/any-docs-for-wp-nav-menus-items-wrap-argument/

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/64515/fall-back-for-main-menu/